# Excessive SQL Server processes for Entity Framework based application

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

We are currently developing a WPF/Entity-Framework based application.  One of our requirements was to allow the user option to select which environment (testing, training, or production) they will connect to when logging in.  Each connection option points to its own database.  In order to do this we are creating new EF contexts in the following way:

```
Public Function NewVectorContext() As VectorEntities
    Dim strDBConn As String = "metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.VectorModel.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.VectorModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.VectorModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""" & VectorConnectionString & """"

    Dim EntityConn As System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection = New System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection(strDBConn)

    Dim MyNewContext as VectorEntities = New VectorEntities(EntityConn)
    MyNewContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = False

    Return MyNewContext
End Function
```

VectorConnectionString is formatted in standard SQL Server fashion:

```
Data Source=OurDBServer;Initial Catalog=OurAppDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=OurUserId;Password=OurPassword
```

and is determined at runtime by user's selection (testing, training, prod).

We have made sure that all new contexts are being disposed of once its job is completed.

The problem is this: when the users are using the application we are seeing hundreds of SQL Server processes in SQL Server's activity monitor. Some individual users have upwards of 30+ processes associated when using the app. Once the user shuts down the app the associated processes all disappear - but while the app is running these processes seem to stick around.

Comment: Issue semi-fixed: Our viewmodels and models were not always being disposed of properly and fragments were obviously still sticking around in memory which revealed themselves with the high number of processes seen in SQL Server Activity monitor. With proper disposal we are seeing less sql server processes being created but there are still a significant number being created - is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed - as I mentioned above part of the solution was proper memory management and making sure that all models and viewmodels were being properly disposed of.  But that only eliminated a small number of the sql server processes we were seeing.  The major culprit was an improperly designed model base class that was creating multiple contexts for each model being instantiated.  Once it was rewritten the problem was solved. Nothing to do with EF.